# Join Table + Group by + Sum + Finding Nth highest sum value

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables -

**Broker Table** ->Column names-->ID,Name,City,branch

**Policy Table** ->Column names-->Policy_num,Broker_id,Premium

I need to find the broker name having 4th highest sum of the premiums.

Please suggest the SQL query for this.

NOTE:I am looking for a query that can run on all platforms.So please don't use 
TOP,LIMIT or ROWNUMBER functions.

I am looking for a query similar to mentioned below,which is just finding 4th highest salary from a table.

```
SELECT Salary
FROM EmployeeSalary Emp1
WHERE 3 = (
                SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT ( Emp2.Salary ) )
                FROM EmployeeSalary Emp2
                WHERE Emp2.Salary > Emp1.Salary
            )
```

Comment: `row_number()` is standard SQL and works on all modern DBMs. The equivalent of `limit` in standard SQL is `fetch first x rows only`

Comment: Actually LIMIT,TOP and ROWNUMBER cant be used.I was asked this question in an interview.The interviewer wanted an answer without the use of LIMIT,TOP etc.

Comment: Yes,but still I am trying to find the answer.Please check my question again I have given a sample query,The answer must use this concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need a `join`, because all the information you need is in the `policy` table.  You can join in `broker` at the end, if you want.

Second, the question is ambiguous, because it doesn't specify how to handle ties.

But basically, you can follow the same structure as the query in your question:

```
SELECT p.BrokerId
FROM Policy p
GROUP BY p.BrokerId
HAVING 4 = (SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM (SELECT SUM(p2.Premium) as sumpremium
                  FROM Policy p2
                  GROUP BY p2.BrokerId
                 )
            WHERE sumpremium >= SUM(p.premium)
           );
```

But ironically, this is a very, very poor way to approach the problem.  Why?  There is no guarantee that the `SUM()` on the two aggregation queries will be *exactly* the same.

This difference can occur in two ways.  If `premium` is a floating point number, then the order of addition can make a difference.  Adding values near zero to a large value loses precision.  So [check](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=95140328b49938924c12c478f74d3a04) this out:

```
select ( (v1 + v2) + v3), (v1 + (v2 + v3))
from (select cast(100000000.0001 as float) as v1, cast(-100000001.0001 as float) as v2, cast(0.000002 as float) as v3) x;
```

Even with fixed point numbers you can still have problems, because adding all the positive numbers first can result in an overflow.

It is really better to do arithmetic calculations once rather than doing them multiple times and then comparing the values.

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
    SELECT B.Broker_ID,A.Name,
    SUM(B.Premium) S_P,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(B.Premium) DESC) RN
    FROM Broker A
    INNER JOIN Policy B ON A.ID = B.Broker_ID
    GROUP BY B.Broker_ID,A.Name
)A
WHERE A.RN = 4
```

Another option you can use TOP twice to get your desired output as below-

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 4  
    B.Broker_ID,A.Name,
    SUM(B.Premium) S
    FROM Broker A
    INNER JOIN Policy B ON A.ID = B.Broker_ID
    GROUP BY B.Broker_ID,A.Name
    ORDER BY SUM(your_id_column) DESC
)A
ORDER BY S
```

Another option considering MSSQL-

```
SELECT *  FROM
(
    SELECT B.Broker_ID,A.Name,
    SUM(B.Premium) S_P,
    COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY SUM(B.Premium) DESC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS RN
    FROM Broker A
    INNER JOIN Policy B ON A.ID = B.Broker_ID
    GROUP BY B.Broker_ID,A.Name
)A
WHERE A.RN = 4
```

Another option considering your sample query-

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT B.Broker_ID, A.Name, SUM(B.Premium) S
    FROM Broker A INNER JOIN Policy B ON A.ID = B.Broker_ID
    GROUP BY B.Broker_ID,A.Name
)A
WHERE 3 = (
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT B.Broker_ID, A.Name, SUM(B.Premium) S
        FROM Broker A INNER JOIN Policy B ON A.ID = B.Broker_ID
        GROUP BY B.Broker_ID,A.Name
    ) B 
    WHERE B.S > A.S
)
```

Comment: I am looking for a query that can run on all platforms.So please suggest something that don't use LIMIT or ROWNUMBER functions.

Comment: @user1678213 Please check I have added another option.

Comment: Actually LIMIT,TOP and ROWNUMBER cant be used.I was asked this question in an interview.The interviewer wanted an answer without the use of LIMIT,TOP etc

Comment: One more option added considering MSSQL.

Comment: I will definitely give you an up vote for your efforts.But please check my question again.I have given a sample query to find Nth highest salary.I need to use this kind of query to answer my question.

Comment: Thanks. Your sample query is just exceptional idea and I like it. I have posted a new option related to your sample script.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199109/discussion-between-user1678213-and-mkrabbani).